# Trying to send all pictures of a directory to Telegram bot user

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I'm trying to send all pictures of a folder to the bot user.
Here is what I tried but it is not working and not even getting any error.

```
path = '~/Documents/mypath/pics'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.jpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
for f in files:
        telegram_bot.sendPhoto (chat_id, f)
```

What is wrong here and how to fix it ?

**Update:** I tried `telegram_bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, open(f , 'rb'))` and it worked but it is sending same pictures multiple times.

Comment: You've added both `python-telegram-bot` and `telepot` tags! By judging your code, I can't quite figure out which one you're using. I might be able to help if it's `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:
`telegram_bot.sendPhoto (chat_id, f)`

- Replace `sendPhoto` with `send_photo`.
- You need to `open` the file when you want to send it.

Like this:

```
telegram_bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat.id, photo=open(f, 'rb'))
```

Now as you can see:

[image: works]

It works, and it only sends the `.jpg` files. (`RickSanchez` was `png`).

Comment: Thanks. It worked but it is sending same photos multiple times. Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Sorry but I'm using Telepot and I tried `telegram_bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, open(f , 'rb'))` after seeing your code and it worked but it is sending same pictures multiple times.

Comment: @man you can edit your question and mention the code you've used, so other people can help you.